# .RowFilter with "IN" and "NOT IN"

Tags: c#, sql

I have a issue with applying a RowFilter to a DataGridView. I do need to apply RowFilter with `IN` and `NOT IN`.

Example:

```
custId in (select custId from loginDetails where date = '01/11/2010')
```

Note: My grid is initially loaded with all customer details from `CustMaster` table. what I need is to filter login details of a customer who logged on today. Field `custId` is also dynamic.

Will this be possible ?

If any alternative please help.

Comment: What actually happens when you apply rowfilter="custId in (select custId from loginDetails where date = '01/11/2010')" ?

Answer (score 1):

How about using LINQ?

```
//1. Pick all of those that you do not want in your code.
//2. Select those that you want.
var result = from record in dtLoginDetails.AsEnumerable()
                where //2. Select all records.
                (!( //Remove the ! sign to use IN/NOT IN
                (from custID in dtLoginDetails.AsEnumerable()
                    where custID.Field<string>("author").StartsWith("C") //1. Select those records that are unwanted.
                    //Note that, in your case you can add it like 
                    //unwanted.Field<DateTime>("Date") = DateTime.Now.Date
                select custID.Field<string>("author") 
                )
                .Contains(record.Field<string>("author"))
                )

                )
                select record;

//Cast as DataView
DataView view = result.AsDataView();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had problems many years ago (.net v1) with views not updating when the tables used by the "IN" changed.  I don't know if the problem is still in the .net framework these days.